# Workflow status does not get marked as completed even after approvals are done

Tags: workflow

We have a SharePoint Approval Workflow which is getting paused after the Approval is done . Below are the steps our workflow is following :-

1. A new item is added to the list.
2. The workflow is started manually.
3. Approvers approve the item.
4. The Content Approval status is updated( For some of the items) OR The workflow gets paused and no status change

Also workflow is paused and can be seen in running workflow i.e. Workflow completed event doesnt get fired even though Approval is done , How to mark worflow status as completed and remove the paused workflow from running workfloww list in worflow history.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I solved by not selecting on the workflow the option:

After the workflow is completed:
 Update the approval status (use this workflow to control content approval)

Although this option is not selected, the item is still shown as approved on the list.

Hope it helps.
Teresa

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is to use task. When the task is created the workflow waits while task is changed, depends on task status you can change workflow status. See [this post](http://elczara.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/basic-custom-sharepoint-2010-approval-workflow-%E2%80%93-part-1/) (also [part 2](http://elczara.wordpress.com/2010/08/22/basic-custom-sharepoint-2010-approval-workflow-%E2%80%93-part-2/)) to understand this approach.

Comment: Mine is OOB Workflow , Status is not changing only for some of the items rest items gets updated fine